# re.findall ignore some variables in between two patterns

Tags: python

I am trying to find the sentence "DELETED -- LVHEAP = 258/64806/65937  RSS = 66621", which needs to be identified with "--LVHEAP", then after I find all these sentences, I'd like to output "66621".

I used:

```
text ="DELETED -- LVHEAP = 258/64806/65937  RSS = 66621"

RSS = re.findall("(?<=-- LVHEAP = )\d+\\S+\\S+(?<=RSS =)\d+",text)
```

It has an empty output, could anyone help me on it?

Comment: To make sure I understand correctly, you have a file with several lines that include `--LVHEAP`, and for each of these lines, you want to extract the number after `RSS = `?

Comment: Yes, Thanks, Nakor!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you intend the `\S` in your original regex to match non-white space characters, but the `\\` means "match \", which is causing the `S` to mean just a literal "S", because the `\` before it was consumed by the `\\`.

But even if you fix that, there are other problems with your original regex.  Here is a simpler one that matches your description of what you want to do:

```
-- LVHEAP = [\d/]+  RSS = (\d+)
```

This means:

```
-- LVHEAP =    a line containing "-- LVHEAP =  "
[\d/]+         followed by one or more digits and '/' slashes
  RSS =        followed by "  RSS = "
(\d+)          followed by one or more digits, which are captured
```

See https://regex101.com/r/LNuF5K/1

An even simpler regex could work, such as:

```
-- LVHEAP = [A-Z\d/= ]+ (\d+)
```

if, for example, the "RSS" might be some other all-caps word.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
import re

outputs = []
for line in lines:
    if "-- LVHEAP" in line:
        matches = re.findall("RSS = \d+", line)
        matches = [ int(match.split(" = ")[1]) for match in matches ]
        outputs.append(matches)
```

Comment: thanks Nakor!  you mean for example: put to-be-searched file as "lines=file.read()", then add above for loop?  it seems outputs is empty.

Comment: It's weird, I tried it with your `text` example, and it worked. 
And yes, basically you have a file, you could do `for line in open(filename)`

Comment: Here is the complete code i tried:   import re
text="-- LVHEAP = 258/64806/65937  RSS = 66621"
outputs = []
for line in text:
    if "-- LVHEAP" in line:
        match = re.findall("RSS = \d+", line)[0].split(" = ")[1]
        outputs.append(int(match))

Comment: Oh no, that's not how I imagined it. So you have a single string with several copies of "-- LVHEAP", not multiple lines?

Comment: If so, do you have exactly one "RSS = " for each "-- LVHEAP"?

Comment: actually i do have multiple  "-- LVHEAP" lines in a file, if i used your code on "text=open(f'file',"r")
outputs = []
for line in text:
    if "-- LVHEAP" in line:
        match = re.findall('RSS = (\S+)',line) " it works now.  But if i switch a single line in "text" as above, it doesn't work.  I don't know why, but it works for me as a input file now.... Thanks!

Comment: It didn't work before because when you did `for line in text`, you were iterating over a string. So each `line` variable was actually a single letter (thus the empty output). When you read the file however, each line is really a line

Comment: Yes, you are right about single string in text.  Thanks a lot!